# How to calculate monthly growth for each unique course in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe in the following format:

```
course_id year month student_id
'Design' 2016 1 a123
'Design' 2016 1 a124
'Design' 2016 2 a125
'Design 2016 3 a126
'Marketing' 2016 1 b123
'Marketing' 2016 2 b124
'Marketing' 2016 3 b125
'Marketing' 2016 3 b126
'Marketing' 2016 3 b127
'Marketing' 2016 4 b128
```

How to calculate growth of every course in every month. I.e. to have the table in the following format
Year Month 'Design' 'Marketing'

```
2016 1  2 1 
2016 2 1 1
2016 3 1 3
2016 4 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot_table` function like:

```
df.pivot_table(index=['year', 'month'], columns='course_id', values='student_id', aggfunc=len).fillna(0).reset_index()
```